# Why am I getting a type error on pi in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, pi, iso-prolog

I am using `pi` as part of a Prolog program I am writing. Here is my only mention of `pi` in the whole program:

```
ArcDistance is ((Degree/ 360) * Diameter * pi).
```

However, when I run the program, I get the following error:

```
uncaught exception: error(type_error(evaluable,pi/0),(is)/2)
```

Am I doing anything wrong in terms of calling/using `pi`? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

In ISO-Prolog, that is, since Cor.2:2012, the atom `pi` is defined with the usual meaning.

Given the response of the system you showed, you seem to use an older version of GNU-Prolog like 1.3. However, it is defined in versions starting with at least 1.4.0.

`pi` is currently defined in IF, B, YAP GNU, SWI, and presumably many other systems.

Comment: Also defined in (recent versions of) CxProlog, ECLiPSe, Qu-Prolog, and XSB. I think also SICstus Prolog but my copy expired recently and I cannot confirm.

Comment: Thanks @false. At first, I wasn't sure it was defined in my GNU Prolog 1.4, but I had a minor case of operator error.

Comment: SICStus update: https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus/ref_002dari_002daex.html . Quoting: "*pi   since release 4.3, ISO*".